# Show that a matrix $P$ can be written as a polynomial in $AA^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X,Y \in M_n$ such that there exists a nonsingular $A$ such that $X=AYA^{-1}$ and $X^*=AY^{*}A^{-1}$. What i've shown is that $(AA^*)X=X(AA^*)$. Now let $A=PU$ be the polar decomposition of $A$, what I'm trying to show is to show is $P$ can be written as a polynomial of $AA^*$ so that I can it would follow that $XP=PX$. How can I write $P$ as a polynomial of $AA^*$?

 
 Any hint would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have $A^* = U^*P$ and therefore $AA^* = PUU^*P = P^2$.

Then $AA^*$ and $P$ commute, so by the spectral theorem, there is an orthogonal matrix $V$ such that :
$$AA^*= V\operatorname{Diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)V^*$$
and :
$$P = V\operatorname{Diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_n})V^*$$

Let $f$ be a polynomial such that $f(\lambda_i) = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Then :
$$f(AA^*) = V\operatorname{Diag}(f(\lambda_i),\ldots,f(\lambda_n))V^* =P$$
So $P$ is a polynomial in $AA^*$.

Comment: Would it follow that $X$ is unitary similar to $Y$?